# Java : save data from UTF-8 file into Sql Server 2008

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, utf-8, file-io

I failed to save data with accents from utf8 file into my SQL Server 2008 table - SQL collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS - (when I do a System.out.print of my insert statement : the accents are OK).

Here's the steps I'm doing :

1) Convert file to String :

```
        File f = new File(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        in.readFully(buffer);
        result = new String(buffer);
```

2) Execute insert :

```
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("charSet", "ISO-8859-1");
            properties.put("user", user);
            properties.put("password", password);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + serverName + ":1433;DatabaseName=" + dbName + "", properties);

            statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To transcode UTF-8 character data to UTF-16 strings, provide the correct encoding to the [String constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

```
new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting charset to ISO-8859-1, set charset to UTF-8. ISO-8859-1 encoding does not accepts all the characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which collation you use, 
it is important to use "N" before  unicode data strings.

Like:

```sql
insert into table(somecolumn) values(N'unicode string')
```